# Unrecognized selector UIDeviceRGBColor countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios10, xcode8-beta6

I know this is kind of a dupe, but I don't have enough reputation yet to comment on the original post and, while I don't have an answer, I do have more useful information (a concrete example). Moderators, feel free to move this to the proper location.

When compiling my code using the latest XCode 8 beta 6 (iOS 10 SDK), I get an exception "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDeviceRGBColor countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000071340'"

This happens during the call:

```
    auto viewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

I have isolated the problem by whittling down my project to the bare minimum that will compile and still exhibit the problem. You can download it here:

[Example project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b7jggae97889xka/Bugtest.zip?dl=0)

Note that I took out lots of code, nearly all classes are gone, which results in a lot of warnings (not errors) for nonexistent classes referenced from the xib. But that doesn't matter, the code still compiles and runs just fine with the iOS 9 SDK. After compiling with the iOS 10 sdk, however, it crashes both in the simulator and on devices running iOS 9.

You can work around the problem by changing "#if 0" into "#if 1" in the file "HackForUnrecognizedSelectorInIOS10.m". This adds a category defining the missing selectors for UIColor. But obviously you can't add that to shipping code, it's just a temporary stopgap measure to continue developing.

I filed a bug report (28153870). But if anyone has any more information on how to avoid this problem without ugly hacks, any information is welcome.

Thanks

Michel Colman

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When I try to compile and run my project with the same configuration (XCode 8 beta 6, iOS 10 SDK), I encountered a similar issue, except that my error message was:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDeviceRGBColor length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000479280'

And I noticed that this issue only occurs when the view is init by using interface files, i.e. Xib and Nib. I solved this issue by:

1. Open your interface file, in the right panel, navigate to the File Inspector tab.
2. Change the attribute highlighted to "iOS 7.0 and Later" (or whatever iOS version later)
   [image]

Then compile and run your project again, this should fix your issue, though I am not sure about the reason behind this. I tried the same with your sample project and it solves the issue too.

Comment: That does indeed solve it! Apparently the deployment target needs to be at least 6.0. I had it set to "Deployment Target (5.1)". Also, when I manually edited the xib in a text editor to set <deployment version="1296" identifier="iOS"/> (1536 is hex 510, i.e. iOS 5.1), the error came back. When I set it back to 1536 (hex 600, i.e. iOS 6.0), it worked OK again.

Comment: O, by the way, I got the [UIDeviceRGBColor length] as well on some occasions. That's why I included both selectors in the ugly hack file in the project. Meanwhile I found out that this hack doesn't really work right: even though the crashes disappear, so does certain functionality. Some buttons stopped working, for example. Although sometimes they did work. There seems to be some nondeterminism going on there.

Comment: This did not work for me. I tried setting the "Later" version but I still get the error. I also looked into the file and I don't see the version that @MichelColman showed. I just see this, <deployment identifier="iOS"/>

Comment: What does this setting do? Why does it fix the issue and what was causing the problem?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I needed to change the project deployment target to 8.0 in the product general settings. Thanks to the hint from the accepted answer!

Comment: This worked for me. But it still seems like a workaround.. is there a explanation anywhere of the cause and/or a fix needed?

Comment: In my case, I had to specify it in the Podfile. That's my fault because Pod logs a warning if the platform is not specified.